# Add elements of two tuples in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sum, tuples

How do I add the elements of two tuples in Haskell to give me a third tuple. The signature is something like,

```
Add :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) ->(Int,Int)
Add a b = ....
```

So far, I am only able to think of this:

```
Add a b = [(x, y) | a = (x1, y1), b = (x2, y2), x=x1+x2, y =y1+y2n]
```

I am very new to Haskell however, so is what I am doing even correct?

Answer (score 7):

What you are doing is not correct. List comprehensions are not the right way to do this.

Using pattern matching to extract the elements of the tuples:

```hs
add :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
add (x, y) (u, v) = (x+u, y+v)
```

Extracting the elements of the tuples using `fst` and `snd`:

```hs
add2 :: (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
add2 x y = (fst x + fst y, snd x + snd y)
```

Also keep in mind that functions can't start with capital letters in Haskell.

Comment: Of these two, what would the type signature by of the add function? I can see that add2 will have the same type signature as the original "Add" I was working with, but what about the type signature of this add you have defined? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both of them have the same signature. The reason it may not be obvious on first glance for `add` is that it is destructuring the incoming tuples on the fly and this may seem a different type signature. I'm going to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

About your attempt, try running it in `ghci` and you'll see an error. As to why, that syntax you're trying to use is know as *list comprehension*, and it is documented [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension); it is syntactic surgar to create *lists*, such as `[1,2,3]`, so it's not the right tool for you, as the ability to sum to pairs, which have type `(·,·)`, not `[·]` (where by `·` I mean "any type").

Below is a non-basic (and probably overkill) way to write the function you want. But setting the target of understand it could be a way to force yourself going deeper in Haskell.

Here it is:

```hs
import Data.Bifunctor (bimap)
import Data.Tuple.Extra (both)

sumTwoTuples x y = uncurry bimap (both (+) x) y
```

How does this work? Let's see

```hs
> :t both
both :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)
```

So `both` takes a function and applies it to both elements of a pair; therefore `both (+)` will apply `(+)` to both sides of the first pair `x`; if that's `(3,4)`, you'll get `((3+), (4+))` (yeah, I'd write it as `(3+,4+)`, but that's illegal syntax).

Now we have this pair of functions `both (+) x`, and we want to apply each of them to one side of the pair `y`.

Here's `bimap`:

```hs
> :t bimap
bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

So it takes 2 functions and applies it to each side of a `Bifunctor` (in our case the `Bifunctor` type `p` is `(,)`).

It's almost what we need, but it takes the two functions as two separate arguments, not a pair containing them.

`uncurry` gives a way to adjust that:

```hs
> :t uncurry 
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

Indeed, `uncurry bimap` has this type:

```hs
> :t uncurry bimap 
uncurry bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b, c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d
```

so it takes a pair of functions and applies each to the corresponding side of the pair `y`, which has type `p b d` with `p` being `(,)` in our case.

Comment: Clever, but a bit overkill compared to the answer offered by @user1984 given the OP's likely level of expertise in functional programming.

Comment: @Chris, sure, but it's a lot of food for thoughts for a new Haskeller :D

Comment: the `Bifunctor p` is `(,)` here. also, with parens `((3+),(4+))` becomes valid syntax.

Comment: Can you clarify the first part of the comment? (Second part fixed, thanks.)

Comment: the `p` in `Bifunctor p` is `(,)`. the type `uncurry bimap :: Bifunctor p => (a -> b, c -> d) -> p a c -> p b d` becomes, specifically, `uncurry bimap :: (a -> b, c -> d) -> (,) a c -> (,) b d` because you're using it with the pairs. it's not the pair `b`. the pair `b` is a value of type `(,)  b d`. (using the same name `b` both for type var and value can be confusing, maybe switch to `x` and `y`?)

Comment: If I ever was to enter that level of sophistication, I’d rather keep symmetry between the two input pairs, and avoid the unnecessary high-order concept of a pair of closures, with something like: `add x y = bimap (curry (+)) (curry (+)) (zipPairs x y)` where the type of `zipPair` would be `(a,b) -> (c,d) -> ((a,c), (b,d))`. Bonus: easily extended to heterogeneous pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the finally produced value of your function starts with a `(`  but a list's type starts with a `[`. They can't match, so your approach can't be right. But we can mend it.

You are correct in trying to pattern match the values with the tuples of variables, but actually the patterns go to the left and values go to the right of the equal sign. And it must be inside a `let`:

```
add1 :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)]   -- NB: added brackets!
add1 a b = [(x, y) | let (x1, y1) = a ; (x2, y2) = b ; 
                         x = x1 + x2 ; y = y1 + y2 ]
```

and actually we don't need that `let` *inside* the list comprehension,

```
add2 :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)]
add2 a b = let { (x1, y1) = a ; (x2, y2) = b ; 
                 x = x1 + x2 ; y = y1 + y2 }    in
       [(x, y)]
```

and now we can just get rid of those brackets, to get the value and the type which you wanted.

---

There's another, a bit tricky way to make your original code work without changing anything *in* it (except fixing the wrong capitalization of `add` and making it the proper `let` syntax of course).

We just *add* one word and enable one extension, and it works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

import Data.Function.Identity

add :: (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> (Int,Int)
add a b = magicWord
  [(x, y) | let { (x1, y1) = a ; (x2, y2) = b ; 
                  x = x1 + x2 ; y = y1 + y2 } ]
```

The magic word is

```
magicWord = runIdentity
```

With that extension, the inferred type for the definition is

```
add :: (Num t1, Num t, Monad m) 
    => (t, t1) -> (t, t1) -> m (t, t1)
```

and since

```
runIdentity :: Identity a -> a
```

using it forces `m ~ Identity` and it just works: the derived type is

```
(Num t1, Num t, Monad m) 
    => (t, t1) -> (t, t1) -> m  (t, t1)
                             Identity a -> a
--------------------------------------------
                           m ~ Identity        , Monad Identity
                              (t,t1) ~ a
--------------------------------------------
(Num t1, Num t) 
    => (t, t1) -> (t, t1) ->           (t, t1)
```

which matches your given type signature

```
     (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int) ->     (Int, Int)
```

since `Int` is in `Num`,

and `Identity` is indeed a monad, one that does nothing at all,

```
newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}
fmap f (Identity a) = Identity (f a)
join (Identity (Identity a)) = Identity a
```

except tagging the values with its tag, which even disappears right away because the type `Identity a` is defined as `newtype`, not `data`.